# Chart-like object (but not a gantt or stacked bar chart) in d3 -- where to start?

Tags: d3.js

I have a chart I've created in excel that I'd like to replicate in d3, but I'm not sure where I should begin.

[image: Mary Magdalene speeches]

It's intended to show which character is speaking at which moment during a play, and so it visually looks similar to a gantt chart or stacked bar chart but it isn't working off of time the way a gantt chart would.  Am I right in thinking that it'd be a bar chart or series of bar charts?  Could I build it up by a series of 1 pixel wide bars, so that each pixel would equal a line in the play?

I'd provide code but I tried to modify the standard stacked bar chart and all I've really been able to do is either make the whole thing blank or modify the canvas dimensions.  So I'd appreciate some suggestions to get me started.

Answer (score 0):

it seems to me that the only (and big!) trouble you'll have here is creating the JSON. Once you have the JSON, it will be a piece of cake! Here is what I thought:

Create a very big JSON that is just 1 big array of hundreds of objects. Each object would be like this:

```
{"character": "John Doe", "place": "tavern", "duration": 5}
```

Then, you'll append the narrow rectangles using an ordinal scale for the places ("place") on y axis, setting the x position according to the cumulative duration of previous speeches and setting the width using the duration of each speech, and using CSS you can color the bars according to the character (using `character` for setting the class).

For this, you would use D3 only for the scales, avoiding the typical `selection().data().enter().append()` pattern and appending each rectangle in a for loop. Let me explain. Suppose you put your JSON in a variable named `data`. Then, you do:

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
    var speech = data[i]
    //rest of the code
}
```

This allow you, for each loop, to know the y position of the bar using `speech.place`, the name of the character using `speech.character`, for the colors, and the duration of the line using `speech.duration`. For calculating the x position, you declare a `var duration;` outside the loop and, inside it, you write:

```
duration += speech.duration;
```

In this approach, once you would use the cumulative duration for x position, the objects in the array must to be in the exact chronological order of the play.

PS: D3 is so nice that you can create an additional value named "line", for each object, with the actual line spoken by the character, and when the user hover over the rectangle he/she will see the text of the speech!

Comment: Thanks!  I've got the json put together but I'm still playing with trying to get your suggestion to work.  I'll let you know how it goes.